# How can I deserialize a JSON array into a native .net data structure?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "records": [{
    "skills": "",
    "u_past_assignment_groups": "",
    "urgency": "3",
    "correlation_id": "",
    "u_program_name": "",
    "u_software_name": "",
    "group_list": ""
  }]
}
```

(This is a truncated version.) But the point is that it is a single element array of key,value pairs.

In native JavaScript it is a very straightforward step to use `JSON.parse` or `eval` in order to convert this JSON to an actual array of key/value pairs, but, in .Net I cannot figure out how to deserialize this JSON into anything meaningful.  I have tried every permutation I can come up with of `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize` and `JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject`.  No matter what I try I continue to get some sort of error about being unable to deserialize or being unable to cast.  Can someone look at this code snippet and tell me how (in native .Net) I can deserialize this into a list or array of key/value pairs?

Do I have to create my own object to store this data?  I mean, I'd hate to have to do that.  It looks like it should easily conform to a native .net data structure.

```
//process response
Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(respStream);
string response = respReader.ReadToEnd();
respStream.Close();
JavaScriptSerializer jsDes = new JavaScriptSerializer();

//***This is the part I can't figure out.***
var objResp = jsDes.DeserializeObject(response);
Dictionary<string, string>[] dicResp = (Dictionary<string, string>[])objResp;
//******************************************

pOutput.InnerText = "Incident Number: " + dicResp[0]["key"];
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing, but please don't use code *snippets* just for code blocks. Use code blocks for that. Code *snippets* are for runnable-in-browser code.

Comment: I see.  Apologies.  I read this forum a good bit, but rarely post.  I will keep remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I pasted your example in the input.txt file.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("input.txt");
JavaScriptSerializer jsDes = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> objResp = (Dictionary<string, object>)jsDes.DeserializeObject(json);
Object[] records =(Object[])objResp["records"];
Dictionary<string,object> results= (Dictionary<string,object>) records[0];
Console.WriteLine(result["urgency"]);
```

I presume that it's complex to read because of your JSON structure. You have "records" as the first entry in an empty array (you open and close the JSON with {}).
Further, inside records, you have another unindexed array whose first entry is the actual dictionary that contains your key/value pairs.

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately I have no control over the format of the JSON in my case.  Your solution worked.  (had to add an "s" to "result" on the last line to make the variables match).  Since I asked for a native .net solution and you gave me one, I marked this as the answer. In the end I downloaded the JSON.net library from codeplex.  It just seems so much more robust.  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: I abide to your decision of using a library. It's much more efficient and a better practice. You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say if you can use third party libraries, but I think Json.NET is better (more features and performance) than the JavascriptSerializer. You could acomplish what you want by using:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
```

More about Json.Net: http://james.newtonking.com/json

Comment: I've seen this library referenced a number of times in my search for a solution, but ultimately I wanted to learn how to do this with native .net objects.  I mentioned that parenthetically in my question.  Ultimately I did download this library and am pleased with it's performance.  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.